# Where do I find more music that is similar to the soundtrack of Prince of Persia (2008 video game)?

Tags: soundtrack

I am looking for music that is Zoroastrian or at least influenced by Zoroastrianism, such as the soundtrack of *Prince of Persia* (2008 video game).

[The eponymous Prince](https://princeofpersia.fandom.com/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(2008)?file=945941_20080528_screen004.jpg) is most likely of [ancient Scythian and/or Pre-Islamic Persian descent](https://www.academia.edu/Documents/in/Pre-Islamic_Persian_History) (the term "Sanskrit Persian" is sometimes used, but this not at all standard).

I am looking for music with similar musical characteristics (rhythm, instruments, mood, language, tempo, etcetera.) as the reference tracks. Zoroastrian philosophical and/or theological themes are appreciated, but the musical characteristics are the primary factors and content that I am searching for.

The producers of the music from *Prince of Persia* (2008 video game) are Stewart Chatwood and Inon Zur.

---

This is an example of one track from the video game:--

---

Here is another track with gameplay alongside the track:--

[**Warning**: Consult this link, < https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1338661/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_stry_5 >, before watching the video directly above. This video game is rated T in the USA]

---

Here is yet another track with gameplay alongside the track:--

[**Warning**: Consult this link, < https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1338661/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_stry_5 >, before watching the video directly above. This video game is rated T in the USA]

---

One of the video game's tracks has a direct reference to Zoroastrianism, though the influence may only be limited to the title of the song:--

Compare the song's title to this:--

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahura_Mazda)

---

**Prior research**:--

- (https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=zoroastrian+music+in+english)
- (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1338661/?ref_=nv_sr_2)
- (http://www.game-ost.com/albums/3604/prince_of_persia_original_soundtrack/)
- (http://princeofpersia.wikia.com/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(2008_Soundtrack))

Comment: Does "Merchant Prince" (Reprised Version) by Two Steps From Hell qualify as what I have described?

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wc7CZqhnSwA)

Comment: If there is no objection, further comments, and/or the like, I shall post "Merchant Prince" as an answer.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you are seeking music related directly to the religion of Zoroastrianism (by lyrical content, philosophy, or authentic use in rituals), or whether you are seeking music with similar *musical* characteristics (rhythm, instruments, mood, language, tempo, etcetera) as the reference tracks.  Also, is there a reason to believe the reference tracks are actually Zoroastrian?  I couldn't find any support for that in your supplied links.

Comment: " ... whether you are seeking music with similar musical characteristics (rhythm, instruments, mood, language, tempo, etcetera) ... "

This is what I am seeking.

One of the video game's tracks has a direct reference to Zoroastrianism, though the influence may only be limited to the song title: <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEcqXtIsL6U>
Compare the song title to this:
<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahura_Mazda>

Comment: @ChrisSunami Please cooperate with me if you see any other problems, to get the question into a better state! :)

Comment: :)  I did edit the question to put it in a form I thought was easier to understand, but you reverted all those changes.  Now that I understand your purpose a little better, I could edit that into the question, but I don't want to change it any more if you prefer your original version.

Comment: I apologize if I have caused you any issues. :)

Comment: I have incorporated some elements of your edits into my answer. One example is the "Prior Research" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Warning**: This answer contains religious content and discusses religion, and it may offend some people.

Ethics is important and very much lacking in our society, so I decided to post this.]

---

[image]

This picture, directly above, links Zoroastrianism with the video game(s).

[image]

[image]

Since this is a strange topic, a picture can explain more than text does. A picture is a thousand words.

I found two songs about Zoroastrianism that are in English:--

---

**Wikipedia on Humanism**:--

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanism)

---

**Notes**:--

[I have separated this as a different answer due to the difference in tone and style of content of both answers.]

Answer (score 1):

"Merchant Prince" (Reprised Version) by Two Steps From Hell qualifies as what is being asked for.

It features a Prince that is possibly from Persia, but it does not explicitly discuss Zoroastrianism.

The song echoes *Prince of Persia*'s (2008 video game) epic, hopeful, and exotic feel while still remaining tinged with a mournful overtone.

---

Here is a video link to that particular song:--

This is an alternate link in-case the link above becomes broken:--

(https://soundcloud.com/twostepsfromhell/thomas-bergersen-merchant-prince)

---

**Notes**:--

- This being a Music Fans Stack Exchange, I shall be slightly less pedantic, but will still be retaining quality, with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The film, [*Lawrence of Arabia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_of_Arabia_%28film%29) (1962 epic historical drama film), has a soundtrack similar to the game's.